# Emails that work with Tor

Tags: email, private

I need a list of non-darknet emails that work fine with Tor. I just need a list of well known email providers(like Google,Hotmail,etc) that work with Tor.
I know Yandex works with Tor, but you get banned after 5days - 1 week.

Answer (score 1):

protonmail is accessible through their own onion site: https://protonirockerxow.onion/